# Fixing Image Size on Smaller Screen - Image Shrinks Too Small

Tags: html, css, image, size

I'm trying to set up a web page so that on a large screen two images are lined up next to one another and lined up on top of each other on a smaller screen. I've managed to do this, but for whatever reason, the images are shrinking smaller than they normally do when lined up on top of each other.

If anyone has any ideas on how to resize the images so that they're easier to see on a smaller screen, it'd be much appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en; jp;">     
    
<body style="background-color: white;">
      
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
      
    <div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ホーム</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ブログ</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">小泉ついて</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">参考文献</a></li>
    
            
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;"/>
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;"/>
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="検索" style=" padding-  
bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 32px;"/>
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html"/>    
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
    
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
}    
    
</script>
         
</div> 
</ul>    
</nav>
</header>     
               
<div class="setsumei">
        
</div>  
    
<br><div class="image" style="margin: 20px;">
<div class=" responsive-image-container">
    
<a href="#"><img src="photos/Home_Page/geiko.JPG" alt="Geiko" width="45%"></a> <a href="#"><img src="photos/Home_Page/fuji.JPG" alt="Fuji" width="45%"></a>
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">小泉© 2020 | <a href="#">日本語</a></footer></div>
      
</div>
      
<style>
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}
    
 .image{text-align: center;}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 20px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -20px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 40px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 480px) {
 .responsive-image-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        
      }
    }
        

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 480px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have added 45% width to img tag, you need override that on mobile screen with css property img{width:100%; height:auto}

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This solved my issue. You're damned good at this!